# Accessing attribute values in an XML structure- C++ using MSXML6

Tags: c++, xml, msxml6

I have this XML file below:

```xml
<catalog>   
  <book id="bk101">
    <author> Gambardella, Matthew </author>
    <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
    <genre>Computer</genre>
    <price>44.95</price>
    <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
    <description>An in-depth look at creating applications with XML.</description>
  </book>
</catalog>
```

I would like to print the attribute inside the `book` node (that being the value of `id`, which is `bk101`), however I'm having trouble using the MSXML6 library to do so, and I would like to stick with it instead of changing to Rapid, etc.

Below is my code so far:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <windows.h>
#import <msxml6.dll> rename_namespace(_T("MSXML"))
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr)) {
        try {
            MSXML::IXMLDOMDocument2Ptr xmlDoc;
            MSXML::IXMLDOMNodePtr bookholder;
            MSXML::IXMLDOMNodePtr author;
            MSXML::IXMLDOMNodePtr title;
            
            hr = xmlDoc.CreateInstance(__uuidof(MSXML::DOMDocument60),
                NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER);
            // TODO: if (FAILED(hr))...
            
            if (xmlDoc->load(_T("books.xml")) != VARIANT_TRUE) {
                printf("Unable to load input.xml\n");
            }
            else {
                printf("XML was successfully loaded\n");

                xmlDoc->setProperty("SelectionLanguage", "XPath");
                MSXML::IXMLDOMNodeListPtr booklist = xmlDoc->selectNodes("/catalog/*");
                bookholder = booklist->Getitem(0);
                //printf(bookholder->Getxml()+"\n"); //works till here
                //printf(bookholder->; //what to do here to print attribute?
            }
        }
        catch (_com_error& e) {
            printf("ERROR: %ws\n", e.ErrorMessage());
        }
        CoUninitialize();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you read the [`IXMLDOMNode` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms765513(v=vs.85)) yet? `IXMLDOMNode` has an [`attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms760261(v=vs.85)) collection.

Comment: Thanks Remy, I was unable to find nice documentation regarding the MSXML library but this looks promising!